# не хватает yaml в php-fpm

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, yaml

Для работы в связке *nginx + php-fpm* нужен модуль *yaml*.

Ставил через `pecl install yaml`. В конце установки вижу:

```
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/yaml-1.2.0
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=yaml.so" to php.ini
```

Сообщение явно говорит о том что я должен добавить в `php.ini`.

Я пытался добавить в `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` и перезапустил *фмп*. Не помогло.

Прошу помощи.

Comment: обратитесь через nginx к `phpinfo()` — там должны быть упомянуты используемые конфигурационные файлы и пути для поиска. убедитесь, что этот `php.ini` читается, а файл yaml.so находится в одном из каталогов, где осуществляется поиск.

Comment: с ямлом разобрался вылезла другая ошибка. Подскажите[error] 22450#0: *43 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/SP/Gear/Dispatch.php on line 107" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.91.216, server: front.lo, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.91.10"

Comment: задавайте новый вопрос: так здесь принято.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

обратитесь через *nginx* к файлу с `phpinfo()` — в выдаче должны быть упомянуты используемые конфигурационные файлы и пути для поиска файлов:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

убедитесь, что нужный `php.ini` там упоминается, а файл `yaml.so` находится в одном из каталогов, где осуществляется поиск файлов.